# Sum of a path on a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I need to take my graph:

```
g = Graph[{A \[UndirectedEdge] B, B \[UndirectedEdge] C, 
   C \[UndirectedEdge] A, C \[UndirectedEdge] D, 
   A \[UndirectedEdge] D, B \[UndirectedEdge] D}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {14, 46, 49, 48, 38, 16}, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

and Find the sum of the weights along an arbitrary path, for example A->B->C->-D->A
I've been trying to use GraphDistance but that only lets me go a single step. Does anyone know how to specify a path instead of just two vertices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Total[GraphDistance[g, #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ 
  Partition[{A, B, C, D, A}, 2, 1]]
```

138. 

---

```
Partition[{A, B, C, D, A}, 2, 1]
```

gives the list of individual path segments.

```
GraphDistance
```

calculates all the lengths of these individual segments.

```
Total
```

adds them up.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to modify your code for the answers I needed, but I'll need to do some research  to figure out what each part is actually doing.